# How to bind a WPF CheckBox to a conditional?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, conditional-statements

**View Model**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding !MyProperty.Equals('Steve')}" />
```

Is this possible? How?

Comment: You can use a converter for that

Comment: This can be done entirely in Xaml without code.

Comment: @GarryVass That gives me faith that a solution exists.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin, I think doing it in Xaml is better because it makes the code less clutttered and more abstract...

Comment: @GarryVass I don't know how to do it in Xaml thought I would like to know.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin, I was going to add that as an answer, but your comment below indicates that you have found a work-around.

Comment: @GarryVass I have found a workaround that is non-ideal. I would love to see your answer.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin, I added an answer that uses triggers that is NOT a work-around.  See if that works better for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of thing can be done (and many say *should* be done) in Xaml without involving logic from the View Model.  To see it work, create a View Model like this...

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myProperty;
    public string MyProperty
    {
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        get { return _myProperty; }
        [DebuggerStepThrough]
        set
        {
            if (value != _myProperty)
            {
                _myProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
            }
        }
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var handler = System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref PropertyChanged, null, null);
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And then bind it to some Xaml that looks like this...

```
<Grid>
    <CheckBox Content="Some check box">
        <CheckBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProperty}" Value="Steve">
                        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </CheckBox.Style>
    </CheckBox>
</Grid>
```

This is a standard WPF Checkbox that has been styled with a data trigger.  The trigger will set the IsChecked property to true whenever the 'MyProperty' property contains "Steve".  Otherwise the CB will be unchecked (per the overriding Setter in the Style).  It works because the trigger listens to changes in the VM's 'MyProperty'.  So visualization is entirely relegated to the user surface.

Triggers can be combined (and even used with Template Selectors) to access powerful functions built-in to WPF; and they will bind to any dependency property on the Check box, like Background colour etc.

Comment: Okay. This makes sense. What is odd how we use a <Style> element to define logic. That seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin, You'll have to take that one up with the WPF forefathers.  Hope the answer helps

Comment: Totally. Much code is non-intuitive. I just checked your answer in my code and it worked perfectly. I even checked enum equality. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of people will suggest a converter, which certainly works. But I've found a much quicker way is to create a new bool property to use and bind to that:

```
public string MyProperty{get;set;}

public bool MyPropertyChecked
{
    get { return !MyProperty.Equals('Steve')}
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. The trick is setting this up with `base.PropertyChanged("MyProperty");` so the UI reflects the change. That is another question, though.

Comment: It has to be two way binding to retain the state of check box. Hence I added a set property for MyPropertyChecked.